# Vue3 ref not getting refreshed?

Tags: vuejs3, ref

I need some help to understand the way refs work. I'm pretty sure I'm making some obvious, basic mistake, but I just don't get it. Can someone please explain?

In the `script setup` I get some props passed from the outer component:

```
const props = defineProps({
    myEvent: Object,
    gridColumnLabels: Object,
    gridColumnOrder: Array,
    isAdmin: Boolean,
    isLoggedIn: Boolean,
    userEmail: String
})
```

Then I have a ref declared:

```
const isMR = ref(props.myEvent.mREmail ? props.myEvent.mREmail?.includes(userEmail) : false)
```

`myEvent.mREmail` may exist or not. I expect that if `myEvent.mREmail` exists, and it includes `userEmail` the `isMR` is `true`.

Now in my template I display:

```
<div>
    userEmail: {{ userEmail }}
</div>
<div>
    props.myEvent.mREmail: {{ props.myEvent.mREmail}}
</div>
<div>
    props.myEvent?.mREmail?.includes(userEmail): {{ props.myEvent?.mREmail?.includes(userEmail) }}
</div>
<div>
    isMR: {{ isMR }}
</div>
```

Here's the result I get rendered:

```
userEmail: qw@as.zx
props.myEvent.mREmail: qw@as.zx
props.myEvent?.mREmail?.includes(userEmail): true
isMR: false
```

[image]

Why, oh why?....

Comment: If you want it to automatically re-evaluate, please consider using a `computed`: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html

Comment: Oh wait, what even is the issue here? You are not expecting `true` as a result? Also, what do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: Well... I'm expecting 'true' indeed. And that's what I get in the second to last line! As you can see: props.myEvent?.mREmail?.includes(userEmail) evaluates to true!

Comment: So, what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is: while expression props.myEvent?.mREmail?.includes(userEmail) resolves to TRUE, ref on top of this exact expression resolves to FALSE.

Comment: On top? Quite blurry explanation so far.

Comment: By "on top" I mean the following isMR definition: const isMR = ref(props.myEvent.mREmail ? props.myEvent.mREmail?.includes(userEmail) : false) - it is based on props.myEvent.mREmail?.includes(userEmail) expression.

Comment: First off, you should not need to use a `ref` with an expression inside of it if you do have a prop because it's passing a ref already. And then, if you want your state to be re-evaluated => `computed` as mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: And that is apparently the right way! Thanks! Now, just for my understanding: why doesn't a `ref` act this way? Is it impossible to use expression in ref? Is that my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using the playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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) with the following

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import Child from './Child.vue'

const localEmail = ref('cool@gmail.com')
</script>

<template>
    <p>parent component</p>
    <input v-model="localEmail" />
    <br />

    <Child :email="localEmail" />
</template>
```

`Child.vue`

```html
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
    email: String
})

const isMatching = computed(() => props.email == 'cool@gmail.com')
</script>

<template>
    ---
    <p>child component</p>
    <p>props from parent: {{ props.email }}</p>
    <p>does it match? {{ isMatching }}</p>
</template>
```

We have the correct boolean if matching the proper email
[image]

And a `false` otherwise
[image]

A `prop` is already reactive and does not need to be wrapped into a `ref` once more.

Vue uses a `proxy` underneath, it breaks the whole principle if you wrap it twice. Give a read to that one for more explanations on the Reactivity system: https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#props

If you want to re-evaluate a specific value, use `computed` for such purpose, it will track the dependencies and react to them accordingly.
More info here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html